# Does WordPress include native mobile support?

Tags: wordpress, mobile

I have setup a site on WordPress that doesn't appear to adapt to mobile sites at all.

I used to use Joomla which had a responsive mode. Does WordPress have any features or settings to adjust appearance or compatibility with mobiles or is it a case of applying a third party plug-in?

Comment: http://www.elegantthemes.com/gallery/handheld/

Comment: From my experience, no. However, there are a number of themes and plugins available to help with this.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really about Wordpress itself but about the theme you are using.

Think of Wordpress as the skeleton of your website. It is there to provide the foundation and core functionality.

Your theme is where the responsive/mobile functionality comes from. Most premium themes are now designed for desktop, tables and mobile. Most will also come with a Theme Panel which will allow you to change settings and etc.

I would check [ThemeForrest Wordpress section](http://themeforest.net/category/wordpress).

Lastly, when are choosing a theme, my strong suggestion is to look for a well established theme. Look for how often the theme is updated, how many support comments are on the page and how often the theme author is engaging with customers.